# C++ Classes returning value from a function another

Tags: c++

UPDATE: Did not call cat.. but receiving an error: No matching function for call to 'category::tostring()' in stop program function

```
    string category::tostring(string cat) {


string record =  cat  + ":" +  _itemDescription + ":" + _price;

return string (record);
}


void orderList::stopProgram(){
ofstream fout("menu.txt");
for(size_t i=0; i< _ca.size(); ++i){
    fout << _ca[i].tostring() << endl;
    }
fout.close();

    cout << endl;
}
```

Tried to various methods, of including the "string cat" inside tostring() in function stop program..but still getting the same error

Comment: Could you please explain your problem? Your code is a part of one function and another function...

Comment: @NewbieHasker By the looks of it you should start with a C++ book or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

It does not return the value *drink* since you initialize the variable wihtout filling data into it:

```
string category::tostring() {
string cat;  // Here you initialize it (it is empty here)
// I guess _timeDescription and _price are global variables.
string record =  cat  + ":" +  _itemDescription + ":" + _price;  // still empty
return string (record);  // still ...
```

Do you have a global variable called `cat` as well? If so, try removing the local instance, but most likely you have simply forgotten to call the method returning a value for `cat`.

The code snippet you show that returns `cat`, does not appear to be called from anywhere, have you forgotten to call it? if so call it and store the return value in `cat`.

UPDATE:

After your question has been updated, where you changed your original code to now include the variable `cat` as a parameter, you have added the following code, in your question:

```
for(size_t i=0; i< _ca.size(); ++i){
    fout << _ca[i].tostring() << endl;
}
```

You do not write what type `_ca` is of, but my guess is that the `tostring` method you call here, is the one from your `category` class, in this case, you miss the `cat` parameter, which you have now included in the function declaration above, in the call to the function.

You should really look at the comment from demonplus, and explain your problem in more details, even include a minimal example that can be attempted compiled on its own, that will present the exact same compilation error that you see.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to call it, but now I'm getting a different error which isn't related to that function, it dislays "Expected primary-expression before 'cat' in another function :/

Comment: @NewbieHasker how do you call the function, how does the code line look after your change to the code?

Comment: I called it by including "string cat inside tostring() and deleted string cat inside it

Comment: Cheers..but i'm just going to re-start fresh